# node app doesn't terminate

Tags: node.js, bash, service

I am trying to run a node app work as a service.

I am using [this](http://blog.terminal.com/using-daemon-to-daemonize-your-programs/) to do so , where I am calling a script:

```
cd $HOME/
$(which node) app.js
```

So , when I start the service , everything is ok.

The problem is that I can't stop the service.If I stop the service, the process is still running and I must do `sudo kill -9 PID` in order to stop it.

In app.js :

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb', function(err, database) {

    if(err) throw err;

    db = database;

    var server = app.listen(1338, function () {
        var host = server.address().address;
        var port = server.address().port;

        server.timeout = 120000;
    });


    process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
        server.close(function () {
                process.exit(0);
        });

    });

});
```

I am not sure if I have to add another process.on statement to handle this ,or this is somekind of another problem.

If I just run the app.js ( not as a service , I am able to stop it with Ctrl+C)

Comment: Have a look at this it's easy to run process as service https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

Comment: @RATS:Thanks!I'll check it!

Answer (score 0):

Replace process signal from `SIGTERM` to `SIGINT`.